# Get the user who created a document library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

For auditing purposed we need to know who create each document library in a SharePoint site (not the document but the document library)
Is there is was we can do it prefereably through powershell so we can automated for all document libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cmdlet does what you want:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://yoursiteurl"
$library = $web.lists["Library Name"]
$author = $library.Author
Write-Host $author
```